# Таблица цен в прайс-листе. Название

Tags: фразеология, заголовок

**Цены на услуги мастеров студии/ Прайс к мастерам студии/ Цены к мастерам студии?**

Уже всё кажется не верным.

Comment: А первый вариант почему? цены на услуги (кого-чего?) вполне нормальный речевой оборот.

Comment: Для замены русской цены на английский прайс должна быть какая-то разумная причина. Иначе выгладит как претензия на оригинальность или проявление дурного вкуса. На мой взгляд, можно принять только прайс-лист — этот термин прижился в русском языке и воспринимается естественно.

Answer (score 1):

Прайс-лист услуг мастеров студии

Кстати если просто оставить **Прайс-лист** будет лучше

Comment: Будут два прайса, у конкретного мастера один, у всех остальных другой

Comment: Прайс-лист может включать имена мастеров и цены на услуги каждого мастера.

Answer (score 0):

Цены за услуги мастеров студии.

Answer (score 0):

Мне чаще всего приходилось встречать формулировку "Прайс на услуги мастера", т.к. "прайс" - это "цена/цены", и выражение "прайс на услуги мастера" эквивалентно, таким образом, выражению "цены на услуги мастера".

Comment: Все-таки прайс - это ед. ч.. Звучит странно, на мой взгляд.

Comment: "Прайс" очень часто используется в качестве сокращения от "прайс-лист" (как в английском, так и в русском языке). Поэтому фразу "сбросьте мне прайс на ваши услуги" мне приходилось читать и слышать в бизнес-окружении намного чаще, чем фразу "сбросьте мне прайсы на ваши услуги".

Comment: Думаю,  именно так: "прайс" как сокращение от "прайс-лист". Но это сленг, и его употребление ограничено.

Comment: Скажем так: варианты "пришлите мне ваши прайс-листы" или "пришлите мне ваш прайс-лист" мне приходилось читать и слышать намного реже, чем варианты со словом "прайс". Могу высказать осторожное предположение, что использование слова "прайс" в качестве сокращения от "прайс-лист" уже является нормой деловой речи, причем не только разговорной, но и письменной. Но это, разумеется, всего лишь мои субъективные ощущения.